# Why does this code re-render SwiftUI view's body?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uitextfield

I'm worried about view's rendering conditions.

I wrote the following code which is property wrapper to implement keychain storage like `AppStorage`.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct SecureStorage {

var store: KeychainStore = KeychainStore()
var key: String

init(_ key: String) {
    self.key = key
}

var wrappedValue: String? {
    get {
        store.get(key)
    }
    nonmutating set {
        store.set(key: key, value: newValue)
    }
}

var projectedValue: Binding<String?> {
    Binding(get: {
        wrappedValue
    }) { value in
        wrappedValue = value
    }
}
```

And I use this code to get keychain value in any view.

```
struct SampleScrollView: View {
  @SecureStorage("userId") var kuserId: String?
  @SecureStorage("password") var kpassword: String?

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        DebugTextView(title: "Password", value: $kpassword)
        TestView()
     }
  }
}

struct TestView: View {
    init() {
        print("TestView init")
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("testview")
        }
    }
}
```

`DebugTextView` is a custom `TextView` made to use an optional String in `textField`, but here this code is omitted because it's a little long.

And here is the point of my concern:
`TestView` is re-rendered every time I changed the value in `DebugTextView`.
"TestView init" is printed every time I change the value in `DebugTextView`.
I confirmed this on the actual iPhone device.

In my opinion, it doesn't regenerate the body except for special values ​​like `@State`, `@ObservedObject`.

Why this code re-render the view's body?

Comment: In my understanding you passed password as binding to DebugTextView, so every time that property changes in DebugTextView, SampleScrollView refreshes its body, which refreshes TestView.

Comment: Thanks you for comment.
My question is how swiftUI observe @SecureStorage value changed. Above code doesn't seem to have a corresponding one.

Comment: You have created your own customPropertyWrapper, @State and other are provided by apple, if you see there implementation internally you will find similar implementation but with more detailed context.

Comment: I believe @State has a private way to tell the ViewGraph to update, so I'm not sure if it's possible to do in in a custom property wrapper, though I'm not an expert in that area. I can suggest an alternative though. Make your KeychainStore an ObservableObject and call objectWillChange.send() when you update a value.

Comment: Thank you for your good comment.
I have already considered your point. So I was confused by the above phenomenon.
I wanted to create a KeychainStore with the same interface as @AppStorage, but I'm going to create the one by using objectWillChange as you say. thx.

Comment: @hiroshi does it work ?, I'm looking for something like this I want `KeychainStore` to act as `@AppStorage`, if you find the sloution could you please answer you own question to help others